# Windows PowerShell to find duplicate lines in a file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to find the duplicate values in a text file using power shell
let's say if the file content is

```
Apple
Orange
Banana
Orange
Orange
```

Desired output should be

```
Orange
Orange
```

Comment: Should it just return the duplicate if it is on the next line? I see Orange 3 times in the input, and only 2 times in the output.

Comment: @Sjark, my requirement was to know whether there are any duplicates in a file. So the output can print Orange two or three times works for me. Anyways thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can also use the Group-Object cmdlet to see if any lines occur more than once:

e.g.

```
Get-Content test.txt | Group-Object | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: Thanks Nasir!! That really helped. I am having a similar problem posted can you please check it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43820264/windows-powershell-to-find-duplicate-values-in-one-of-the-two-columns-in-a-text

Answer (score 2):

Used the Commands mentioned below and it worked.

```
PS C:\Projects> $OriginalContent, $UniqueContent = (Get-Content .\File.txt), (Get-Content .\File.txt | Sort-object -unique)
PS C:\Projects> compare-object $originalcontent $uniquecontent
```

or to print the text and the count use the following command

```
PS C:\Projects> Get-Content .\File.txt | group-object
```