# Find duplicate values in one of the two columns in a text file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a text file with two values in each line separated by a space. Now I want to know duplicate values in one of the columns. Is it possible to achieve this using Windows powershell.

Given a text file:

```
Apple Fruit
Banana Fruit
Carrot Vegetable
```

Desired output is: (I want to find duplicates in second column)

```
Fruit
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `Import-CSV` cmdlet and specify a *whitespace delimiter* to easy get access of the second column. Then you can *group* the objects using the second column and select the one with more than 1 entries:

```
Import-Csv 'path_to_your_text_file' -Delimiter ' ' -Header @('first', 'second') | 
    Group-Object second | 
    Where-Object count -gt 1 | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
```

Comment: -Header first, second are enought not necessary to use array ;)